# keep track of a sum in a nested list?

Tags: nested-lists, depth, accumulator

I need to keep track of the value at index 0 for each instance of a list inside a nested list.

E.g. n = [2, [3, [1], [2]], 2]

The largest depth length is 3, so I need to add 2 + 3 + 1. The problem is, the function used to return the depth of the nested list is recursive, and I can't figure out where to add an accumulator.

```
def depth(lst):
if isinstance(lst, list):
    return 1 + max(depth(item) for item in lst)
else:
    return 0
```

where can I accumulate the values along the path leading to the highest depth?